# Define an API endpoint in Angular2 (typescript)

Tags: typescript, angular

I am very new in Angular2.
I would like to have a single class having all my API endpoints (allowing parameters and such in the different routes) that I could inject in all my services.
What's the best way to do so in Angular2. I mean, should I define an `@Injectable class` as you would do when defining a service (and then add it to my services'`PROVIDERS`) or is it something similar to `constant` in angular 1.x that I could use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an **@Injectable Class**, so you can compose the API if you need so.
 I have an API service which is injected in the bootstrap(**app singleton**) and it's used in all other services, this is how it looks like :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
    // Hardcoded user :
    private user: string = '/user/1';

    get userCars() {
        return `${this.user}${API.userCars}`
    }

    get userRegisterCar() {
        return `${this.user}${API.userRegisterCar}`
    }

    get profile() {
        return this.user;
    }
}

const API = {
    userCars: '/usercar/details=true',
    userRegisterCar: '/usercar/registration/'
}
```

Comment: How does that work if that I don't want user 1, but user x ?

Comment: You will have another setter/method which will update the user. Something like set user(userID) {this.user = `/user/${userID}`}

Answer (score 0):

you may try directly adding a constant file which exports all your constant if that solves your purpose,

**constants.ts**

```
    export var APPCONSTANTS: any = {
       GETDATA_API_PATH  : "some path here"
    }
```

If you want intellisense you will have to define a interface which will list all possible properties like below and give the type of APPCONSTANTS as IAppConstant,

```
  interface IAppConstant{
      GETDATA_API_PATH: string
  }
```

import constant and use,

```
   import { APPCONSTANTS } from "./constants"; // give relative path
   ...
   ...
   let x = APPCONSTANTS["GETDATA_API_PATH"];
   or 
   let x = APPCONSTANTS.GETDATA_API_PATH";
```